# Angular 4 + Angular Universal + NGXerrors "Unexpected token import"

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, angular-universal

So I have standatd Angular 4, Angular Universal app with using [ngxerrors plugin](https://github.com/UltimateAngular/ngx-errors). During running compilation for server I get error

```
Unexpected token import. (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { Directive, Input, Inject, HostBinding, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';

/var/www/html/licz_kalorie/client/node_modules/@ultimate/ngxerrors/src/ngxerror.directive.js:1
```

I understand that node cannot compile `import` `export` keywords. I'm looking for solution not only for this particular plugin, but for another plugins in future that uses `import`.

I googled and found this solution, which uses `webpack.config.js`

```
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
    ...
    target: 'node',
    externals: [nodeExternals({
    whitelist: [
        /^@ultimate\/ngxerrors/
        ]
    })],
    ...
}
```

**But it does not work. How can I resolve this issue?**

Comment: Hi, did you managed to get the webpack.config.js file working? I'm having the same issue with all my third party libs. Any help would be great